# text-anchor don't appear in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm having trouble positioning the text in the position I wanted, I wanted the number corresponding to the bar to appear inside the bar at the top. For this I am manipulating the `text-anchor` which I think should suggest as `center`, am I wrong? Even in some other way I can not get what I want.

```js
        var w = 450;
        var h = 200;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("fill", "#black");

        var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18,
17, 16, 18, 23, 25];
        var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 22)
            .attr("height", 100);
   
        rects.attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        });

        rects.attr("y", function(d,i){
            return h - (d * 4);
        });

        rects.attr("fill", function(d,i){
            return "rgb(0,0," + (d * 10) + ")";
        });

        svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor","center")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length)-1;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return h - (d * 4)-1;
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fail</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.bar {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-right: 2px;
            background-color:teal;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <rect class="div_d3"></rect>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you looked in the docs what are the valid values for `text-anchor`?

Comment: yes, i try with `middle`, `center`, `end`, `right`, ... And nothing

Comment: I am able to change your anchor by using your code and start, middle, end, everything works as expected. You probably want to add half a bar's width to the x attribute though: you don't want the anchor point to be the left hand side of the bar but rather the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this might be to use

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,<height_of_text>)')
```

where `<height_of_text>` would send the text downward by a specified amount. To use the actual text height, you could use something along the lines of the return value of

```
svg.selectAll("text").node().getBoundingClientRect().height
```

I don't know of a flag in text-anchor that can do it directly.